# Addition of a matrix and a vector

Tags: matrices, vectors

I was reading a book on deep learning [1] and came across an equation like this:

$$ C_{i,j} = A_{i,j} + b_{j} $$

This is an equation for showing how an addition of a matrix and a vector is done. But I think instead of $b_j$ it should be $b_i$ since vectors doesn't have a $j$ index. Please tell me if I am wrong and why? Thanks.

Quote from the book:

> In the context of deep learning, we also use some less conventional notation. 
>  We allow the addition of matrix and a vector, yielding another matrix $$C = A + b$$ where $ C_{i,j} = A_{i,j} + b_{j} $. In other words, the vector $b$ is added to each row of the matrix. This shorthand eliminates the need to define a matrix with $b$ copied into each row before doing the addition. This implicit copying of $b$ to many locations is called broadcasting.

[1] *Goodfellow, Ian; Bengio, Yoshua; Courville, Aaron*, Deep learning, Adaptive Computation and Machine Learning. Cambridge, MA: MIT Press (ISBN 978-0-262-03561-3/hbk; 978-0-262-33743-4/ebook). xxii, 775 p. (2016). [ZBL1373.68009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1373.68009). Free Online Version and Errata on https://www.deeplearningbook.org

Comment: You can't add a matrix and a vector. Either you are misunderstanding what the author is saying, or else the author was drunk.

Comment: Can you provide more context for the statement in the book so we can try and understand the intent?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question this is a deep learning book. It says "We allow the addition of matrix and a vector" so this addition is under scope of the deep learning field. If you curious about how addition of matrix and a vector is possible, you can check the "MIT Deep Learning Book" by Ian Goodfellow, Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville. @GerryMyerson

Comment: I edited it @GrapefruitIsAwesome

Comment: The index $j$ in $b_j$ just refers to the fact that you are adding the $j$-th entry of $b$ to the $j$-th *column* of $A$. Therefore the number of columns in $A$ should be the same as the number of entries in $b$.

Comment: Which book? Which chapter?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I think that helps clarify the intent.

Comment: If you had said that in the first place....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the author is thinking in [Python](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.broadcasting.html). The proper matrix notation would be $$ {\bf C} =  {\bf A} + {\bf 1} {\bf b}^\top $$

Comment: Pardon my confusion, but is this what the author meant? Maybe I misunderstand but the identity multiplied by the vector is either just the diagonal (which does not add all of b to each row) or you mean some other product which I'm unfamiliar with - an outer product here may result in a matrix which is too large for component-wise addition. Help?

Comment: Ahhh is this an outer product between a column of 1's and $\textbf{b}^T$ then?

Comment: @SubSevn Replying to the 2nd comment, yes, that is correct.